Short story about a boy who meets a dwarf in his garden, travels to a parallel world where people become mist and rescues his mom
I am trying to find a science fiction short story I read a few years ago. It would likely have been in a sci-fi anthology (multiple authors) or in a "Best of Phillip K Dick" book, but from looking through the latter's works I have not been able to find it.
What I remember from the story:

A boy finds a dwarf in his garden. The dwarf had been squirreling away random items from the house
The dwarf shows the boy how to travel to another world but warns the kid that if he stays there too long he might become mist
He travels to this world and finds a tree where his mother (who he thought was dead) has mostly become mist
He somehow manages to save his mother and they both return to the real world

The story wasn't overly long, probably under 100 pages, but I do not know the original publication date.

Posted elsewhere (currently unanswered) - https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1ea9orj/tomtshort_story_science_fiction_short_story_where/

Someone on reddit got back to me with the answer: "Space Boy" by Orson Scott Card

Space Boy by Orson Scott Card

Is it space that children dream of, or merely visiting other worlds? Todd had always set his heart on being an astronaut, but when he meets an alien and travels to another world, he doesn't use a spaceship, he just hangs out in his own back yard. In Space Boy, Orson Scott Card, author of Ender's Game, takes readers into a strange and wonderful future, where people from another world regularly visit Earth - usually without being noticed. And when humans travel to their world, they find themselves dangerously weak and powerless. Until Todd finds a way to set both worlds to rights. By turns funny and painful, Space Boy is Card at his best, exploring human nature for the entertainment of readers young and old.

This review mentions the mother.

To briefly synopsize, the story focuses on a boy named Todd who has two primary driving characteristics: (1) he wants to be an astronaut when he grows up, but is convinced that there is no way he will ever qualify, and (2) his mother disappeared four years before the beginning of the story, and nobody knows what happened to her or where she went. Over the course of the story, we learn that Card has humorously taken the concept of "wormholes" quite literally; the characters must travel through the bodies of actual interstellar worms to reach their destinations. This leads to frequent use of words like "anus" and "poop" which some adult readers seem to find offensive. I see that stuff as part of the mildly scatological juvenile humor of the book; it places it squarely in the realm of fiction written for the tween boy crowd. It's certainly no worse than the potty humor in the Shrek movie series.

Thanks to everyone for looking, in the end a reddit user got back to me with the answer.

Don't forget to come back and accept by clicking on the checkmark. As a self-answer, you won't be able to do so for two days, but you can click early and it will tell you when you can complete it.
